# Meaning of pulse driven sequential logic?

Tags: synchronization, sequential-circuit

I am trying to understand the meaning of this scheme, providing a sort of classification of sequential logic circuits. This taken from
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_1.html

[image]

Does anybody understand what "pulse driven" stands for? I am 100% fine with "event driven" and "clock driven". I am missing the meaning of the pulse part. In the beginning I was thinking about edge triggering but I don't see why one should create a separate class: if it's the leading edge of a periodic clock signal I would put it under the "clock driven" group... while if it is a random pulse, this looks like an "event driven" evolution to me. Or is it even something fancier like RSFQ?! Unlikely.

Any hint or reference? I need to use these graphics but I could find no clear reference in textbooks.

Comment: (There used to be a time when *latches* (level driven) and *flip-flops* were a thing. And among clocked/synchronous denominations like single-edge-driven/edge-driven and dual-edge-driven/pulse-driven.)

Comment: While electronics-tutorials.ws even recites [7400 series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400-series_integrated_circuits) flip-flop part numbers, it seems to never mention quantum logic. Caution about *event driven*: They use *event* in the context of mundane logic gates… (I don't understand the distinction intended "at the switch(&capacitor)-level". I see (two) discernible design approaches.)